Inside PnP Modern Search WebPart SPFx, Can we force a link to open in a popup window inside the Detailed List layout?
I have the following setting inside my PnP Modern search result PnP Modern Search (v4):

I define to use SharePoint Search, as follow:


Use the Detailed list layout, as follow:


Inside the Manage columns section:



I added this formula for one column, to open the item details  in a new tab:
<a
  href="{{slot item @root.slots.PreviewUrl}}"
  data-interception="off"
  target="_blank"
  style="color: {{@root.theme.semanticColors.link}}"
>
  {{slot item @root.slots.Destination}}
</a>

Currently the link will open in a new tab without any issues. But how to force the link to open in a popup window instead of a new tab?
